# How to speed up this mysql join query

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, explain

I have the following query which takes quite a long time (about 1 min):

```
SELECT `transaction`.`fuel_terminal_id`, `transaction`.`xboard_id`, `transaction`.`gas_station_id`, `transaction`.`operator_id`, `transaction`.`shift_id`, `transaction`.`fuel_type`, `transaction`.`purchase_type`, `shift`.`num` AS `shiftNum`, `shift`.`shift_state_id` AS `shiftStateId`, `shift`.`start_totalizer_dispenser_1` AS `startTotalizerDispenser1`, `shift`.`start_totalizer_dispenser_2` AS `startTotalizerDispenser2`, `shift`.`end_totalizer_dispenser_1` AS `endTotalizerDispenser1`, `shift`.`end_totalizer_dispenser_2` AS `endTotalizerDispenser2`, min(shift.start_time)AS shiftStartTime, max(shift.end_time)AS shiftEndTime, count(*)AS groupCount, sum(fuel_cost)AS sumFuelCost, sum(payment_cost)AS sumPaymentCost, sum(actual_amount / 100)AS sumActualAmount, min(start_fuel_time)AS firstFuelingDate,max(end_fuel_time)AS lastFuelingDate 
FROM `transaction` 
LEFT JOIN `shift` 
ON shift.gs_id = TRANSACTION .gas_station_id 
AND shift.terminal_id = TRANSACTION .fuel_terminal_id 
AND shift.id = TRANSACTION .shift_id 
AND shift.start_time = TRANSACTION .shift_start_time
GROUP BY `transaction`.`gas_station_id`, 
`transaction`.`fuel_terminal_id`, 
`transaction`.`shift_start_time`, 
`transaction`.`fuel_type`, 
`transaction`.`purchase_type`,  
`transaction`.`operator_id`;
```

I could speed up the query (about 25%) by changing the data size of the column "operator_id" in table "shift" from VARCHAR 255 to VARCHAR 16 and also changing data type of this column in the table "transaction" from TEXT to VARCHAR 16. However, still I need more speed up (maybe by adding more indexes or changing them?).

This is the result of EXPLAIN:
[image]

I've read in [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#explain_select_type) that if the column "possible_keys" is NULL, there are no relevant indexes. So, I was wondering if someone can help me understand whether I didn't select the right indexes or not? These are the indexes I put on table "transaction":

[image]

Comment: You select everything from the `transaction` table. When you select everything from a table - there is no need in indexes.

Comment: @zerkms: I selected only 7 columns from the `transaction` table (it has 26 columns in total)

Comment: You have selected all rows.

Comment: @zerkms: sorry but I don't understand your point.. I understand from the EXPLAIN result that the table transaction is scanned completely. Also from the MySQL reference manual, since the possible key column is NULL, I thought maybe I should add more indexes on this table. am I misunderstood? or do you have any idea how could I speed up my query?

Comment: It is scanned completely because you're selecting all the rows. Replace HDD with SSD, it's io problem (scientific guess)

Comment: Can you format your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just found that the problem in my case was not related to indexes or the query or db structure. When I ran the query on my local server, it was fast while on live db was very slow. After some searching, I found that increasing the buffer_pool_size (a bit larger than your DB size, in my case, I increased it from the defult value (8M) to 2G) improves innoDB performance.

Reading the following links helped me understand the Buffer pool in innoDb and how to configure it:

[MySQL Reference Manual: the innoDB buffer pool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html)

[Choosing innoDB buffer pool size](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/11/03/choosing-innodb_buffer_pool_size/)

[What to set innoDB buffer pool and why](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19164/what-to-set-innodb-buffer-pool-and-why/19181#19181)

[MySQL Reference Manual: Configuring innoDB buffer pool size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL rarely finds it prudent to use more than one index per table, so adding all those indexes did not help *this* query.  In a moment, I will present a 'composite' index that may help.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table; we are having to guess at too many things.  And that might help us address your questions about `TEXT`, etc.

The query is a variant on

```
SELECT a.stuff, b.stuff
    FROM a
    JOIN b ON ...
    -- no WHERE clause
    GROUP BY a...
```

Without a `WHERE` clause, it needs to scan all of one table, reaching into the other table.  Which table to start with?  It might not matter.  So what can be done?  There is one other *possibility*.  By having a 'composite' index completely matching the `GROUP BY`, the Optimizer *might* use it to avoid the "Using temporary, Using filesort"; that would help *some*.

```
`transaction`: INDEX(`gas_station_id`, `fuel_terminal_id`, `shift_start_time`,
                     `fuel_type`, `purchase_type`,  `operator_id`)
               -- in that order
 shift: INDEX(gs_id, shift.terminal_id, id, start_time) 
               -- in any order
```

However, if `shift` already has `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, then the new `shift` index is not useful.  Then comes the question of "Why are you `JOINing` on more than `id`?"

There is another possibility...  But first... Which table is `fuel_cost` in?  Ditto for the rest of the columns in the aggregates (`SUM`, ...).  If they are all in `shift`, then there might be another way to write the query that avoids the horrendous expansion via the `JOIN`, followed by collapse via `GROUP BY`.  That is the real performance killer.

(re @zerkms) Because of the way data is structured in a table, the number of *rows* fetched is more important to performance than the number of *columns*.  (I hesitate to be more specific, since `TEXT` can make a difference.)

Comment: Thanks Rick for your useful tips. I just found that my problem was not related to indexes or the query, but it was the small size of buffer pool. so I just increase the innodb_buffer_pool_size from 8M (default) to 2G and it works fine now:)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see an operator_id column in the shift table in your example, so I don't understand how changing the data type could improve the performance of the query...

having said that indexing all the columns being joined should be the best index strategy, e.g. an index should be created for the following fields:

```
shift.gs_id
shift.terminal_id  
shift.id  
shift.start_time
```

As Zerkms correctly points out below, you are performing a full table scan on the transaction table so there's no need add indexes there.

However MySQL will not use indexes on joins where the datatypes are not the same e.g. you can't join a a field with a VARCHAR(32) datatype with a field with a INT datatype and expect an index to be used, so you should make them the same on both sides of the join. If they're not the same, or can't be changed to be the same then there's something fishy about your design.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already have indexes on all the fields you suggested except `transaction.shift_id`. I added this too, but did not change anything :|

Comment: Are the datatypes on both sides of the joined columns consistent? - Can you post the DDL for the indexes (including primary keys)

Comment: Separate indexes for this query will not change anything. "e.g. the following fields should all be indexed" --- this is a harmful advice. What is it based on?

Comment: @Scoindy: yes , I checked them too. They are the same type and size.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a 'separate index'. Additionally, if would be most helpful if comments like this are accompanied by some sort of rational or reasoning.

Comment: @Scoindy by "separate" I mean "not composite". "Additionally, if would be most helpful if comments like this are accompanied by some sort of rational or reasoning" --- well, it should be the opposite: the answer should provide some. But anyway: 1. the OP selects all rows from the table 2. There is a `LEFT JOIN` so `GROUP BY` will not use indexes anyway. 3. Mysql can use 1 index per table per query. Based on 1-3 I don't see how your suggestion is reasonable.

Comment: The only meaningful advice is to create a *composite* index over `shift`

Comment: @zerkms: I already created composite index over table `shift` (gs_id, terminal_id, start_time). and EXPLAIN shows it used the indexes for `shift` table. so, I think maybe I should do sth about the table `transaction`

Comment: @zerkms: by saying `Mysql can use 1 index per table per query.`, do you mean I can't speed up the query by adding indexes on the table  `transaction`? (since it already used indexes of table `shift`?)

Comment: I was, of course, suggesting composite indexes, not an index on each column. If my wording was unclear to you then I guess we just have a different turn of phrase. I did however miss the outer join so yes you are correct about the full table scan on transaction making indexing this table useless.

Comment: @zerkms: so, could you please help me understand what I read in MySQL manual about adding indexes when possible key in EXPLAIN is NULL? `If this column is NULL, there are no relevant indexes. In this case, you may be able to improve the performance of your query by examining the WHERE clause to check whether it refers to some column or columns that would be suitable for indexing. If so, create an appropriate index and check the query with EXPLAIN again. `

Comment: @mOna so what exactly you cannot understand? You don't filter the table, you select everything.

Comment: I don't understand that you said I select everything.. Do you mean since it is a left join, it select all rows form table 1 (transaction)? I thought it does not need to scan the whole "transaction" table because I selected only 7 columns from this table.. I think I am a bit confused about how this query is running..

Comment: The number of _columns_ being `SELECTed` is _relatively_ unimportant; the number of _rows_ is very important.  You are selecting all rows in `transaction` and we can't tell about `shift`.